# Python Code samples for GData Document List API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api, gdata-python-client

Since the change to Google's developer documentation, I can't seem to find any code samples. In particular I am looking for usage examples for

- Searching Documents
- Export documents in various formats
- User impersonation for Google Apps users

I am following the links off the developer pages
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

Does anyone know of links to official examples? Alternative other example resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python documentation is being rewritten, in the meanwhile you can use the sample included in the library to see how to perform all common tasks:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/docs/docs_v3_example.py

API docs here: http://packages.python.org/gdata/docs/api.html

Comment: Thanks Claudio, good to know that it's still going to be available.